# Golang template : Use pipe to uppercase string

Tags: string, templates, go, uppercase

I want to upper case a string in a golang template using `string.ToUpper` like :

```
{{ .Name | strings.ToUpper  }}
```

But this doesn't works because `strings` is not a property of my data.

I can't import `strings` package because the warns me that it's not used.

Here the script :
http://play.golang.org/p/7D69Q57WcN

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but: if you're rendering HTML with this template, have a think about whether the uppercasing is just presentational. If it is, use CSS's `text-transform: capitalize` instead – this is even [language aware](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just use a [FuncMap](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#FuncMap) like this ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/z-yyM6mVt8)) to inject the ToUpper function into your template.

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

type TemplateData struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        "ToUpper": strings.ToUpper,
    }

    tmpl, _ := template.New("myTemplate").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(string("{{ .Name | ToUpper  }}"))

    templateDate := TemplateData{"Hello"}
    var result bytes.Buffer

    tmpl.Execute(&result, templateDate)
    fmt.Println(result.String())
}
```